# slow color changing animation effect on div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to make a div box change color slowly on mouse over .

js code

```
$('#link').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow', function(){
 $('#link').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow');
 })
```

css code

```
#link
{
width:500px;
height:52px;
border:dashed #666 2px;
margin-top:293px;
}
```

html code

```
<div id="link"></div>
```

Comment: CSS `animation`, maybe? PS: jQuery's animate method doesn't animate colors. You have to use a plugin. Like this: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go . you can use the jquery `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events

```
$("#link").on("mouseover",function(){
   $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"red"},'slow');
}).on("mouseleave",function(){
   $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"white"},'slow');
});
```

You will also need the [JQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/) to make this work.`animate` is part of the JQuery UI Library.

Here is the [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KLF9X/18/)

Answer (score 4):

#### Use CSS `animation`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/wMxUu/)

**CSS**

```
#link
{
    width:500px;
    height:52px;
    border:dashed #666 2px;
    margin-top:293px;
}

#link:hover {
        animation: color 1s ease-in-out 0 1 normal both;
}

@keyframes color {
    0% { background: white; }
    100% { background: #F6F6F6; }
}
```

#### Using CSS `transition`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/wMxUu/1/)

**CSS**

```
#link
{
    background: transparent;
    width:500px;
    height:52px;
    border:dashed #666 2px;
    margin-top:293px;
    transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
}
#link:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a javascript function like this

```
  var div = document.getElementById( 'div_id' );
  div.onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName( 'h2' );
    h2s[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  };
  div.onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName( 'h2' );
    h2s[0].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  };
```